# Not able to use Modern UI Charts for Windows 8

Tags: .net, charts, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to use [Modern UI Charts](https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/) for my Windows Store app but I am not able to get it working.(Cannot see the Chart)

A similar issue was logged by another person [here](https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/workitem/16197) along with the code

Can anyone please help??

Comment: Explain your problem, what are you facing ?

Comment: The chart is not being displayed. I cannot see the chart

Comment: Try to use [OxyPlot](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/) charts, it's also free & open source.

Comment: Thanks a lot Xyroid.. Never tried Oxyplot.. OxyPlot looks good but this Modern UI Charts looks much better(in terms of UI).. Looking for help with Modern UI Charts..

Comment: Sample app is working on your machine or not ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

[Getting started with free Metro (Modern UI) charts for Windows 8](http://igrali.com/2013/05/25/getting-started-with-free-metro-modern-ui-charts-windows-8/)

---

I have just created [NuGet package of Modern Chart](https://nuget.org/packages/ModernChart). Install it from there. Uninstall any previous library of modern chart.

I am also giving you the demo of chart. First create new page and add this code. That's it!

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    ...
    ...
    ...
    xmlns:chart="using:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart" -->
    ...
    ...
    ...>

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <chart:PieChart Width="400"
                        Height="400"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        ChartSubTitle="Chart with fixed width and height"
                        ChartTitle="Minimal Pie Chart"
                        >
            <chart:PieChart.Series>
                <chart:ChartSeries DisplayMember="Category"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}"
                                   SeriesTitle="Errors"
                                   ValueMember="Number" />
            </chart:PieChart.Series>
        </chart:PieChart>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TestClass> Errors { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Errors = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
        Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "Globalization", Number = 75 });
        Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "Features", Number = 2 });
        Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "ContentTypes", Number = 12 });
        Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "Correctness", Number = 83 });
        Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "Best Practices", Number = 29 });
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: By the way Just wanted to know what changes you made to the existing package.. Thanks

Comment: Can you help me with the PieSlice SelectionChangedEvent or something similar as I need to Display the selected item details in a textblock

Comment: Please create new question if you want any kind of help.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669006/onselectionchanged-event-for-chart-controls-in-modern-ui-charts-for-windows-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669006/onselectionchanged-event-for-chart-controls-in-modern-ui-charts-for-windows-8)

Comment: Have you changed something in the code or simply created a NuGet package?

Comment: No I just created the NuGet package.

Comment: @Xyroid need help with this  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727838/role-based-view-xaml

Comment: This is excellent thank you!  I was trying to figure out what was going on when the seemingly uber-simple walkthrough in the tutorial wasn't working.  My question is, what ended up being the cause of the problem?

Comment: There should be also targeted option for Windows 8.1