# OnSelectionChanged event for chart controls in Modern UI Charts for Windows 8

Tags: .net, windows-8, charts, winrt-xaml, modern-ui

I am using Modern UI Charts for Windows 8 and I need to do a drill down when the user selects a series item in the chart
(for eg: I have a Column Chart which shows a student Year wise performance and when user selects a particular Column I should show another Column chart with the score he obtained for that particular year in each subject)

I am looking for some kind of selectionchanged event or something similar so that I can change the input to the series to get a different chart

Please Help!!

Comment: I think, it's not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I have intentionally not implemented any events in the charts. You can use a two-way data binding to react on changes.

You can bind a property of your view model to the SelectedItem property of the chart and you get notified if the selection changes.

See the sample in the documentation http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/documentation#howto1

With this approach you could directly bind a second chart to the SelectedItem property and all "magic" is done by data binding.

Cheers, 
Torsten

Comment: Great work @Torsten. The controls made are much better in terms of UI when compared to the other charts that are available for WinRT

Comment: Thanks a lot Torsten! Got it. Didn't try the Two Way binding in my sample app.